# How is the equation for the relation between prediction error, bias, and variance defined?

Tags: variance, bias, generalization

I'm reading this article [Understanding the BiasVariance Tradeoff](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html). It mentioned:

> If we denote the variable we are trying to predict as $Y$ and our
>   covariates as $X$, we may assume that there is a relationship relating
>   one to the other such as $Y=f(X)+\epsilon$ where the error term
>   $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with a mean of zero like so
>   $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\,\sigma_\epsilon)$.
>
> We may estimate a model $\hat{f}(X)$ of $f(X)$. The expected squared
>   prediction error at a point $x$ is: $$Err(x)=E[(Y-\hat{f}(x))^2]$$
>   This error may then be decomposed into bias and variance components:
>   $$Err(x)=(E[\hat{f}(x)]-f(x))^2+E\big[(\hat{f}(x)-E[\hat{f}(x)])^2\big]+\sigma^2_e$$
>   $$Err(x)=Bias^2+Variance+Irreducible\ Error$$

**I'm wondering how do the last two equations deduct from the first equation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If:
$$Err(x)=E[(Y-\hat{f}(x))^2]$$
Then, by adding and substracting $f(x)$,
$$Err(x)=E[(Y-f(x)+f(x)-\hat{f}(x))^2]
$$
$$= E[(Y-f(x))^2] + E[(\hat{f}(x)-f(x))^2] + 2E[(Y-f(x))(\hat{f}(x)-f(x))]$$
The first term is the irreducible error, by definition. The second term can be expanded like this:
$$E[(\hat{f}(x)-f(x))^2] = E[\hat{f}(x)^2]+E[f(x)^2] -2E[f(x)\hat{f}(x)] $$

$$=E[\hat{f}(x)^2]+f(x)^2-2f(x)E[\hat{f}(x)] $$

$$= E[\hat{f}(x)^2]-E[\hat{f}(x)]^2+E[\hat{f}(x)]^2+f(x)^2-2f(x)E[\hat{f}(x)] $$

$$= E\big[(\hat{f}(x)-E[\hat{f}(x)])^2\big] + (E[\hat{f}(x)]-f(x))^2 $$

$$= Bias^2+Variance$$

Then the only thing that is left is to prove that the third term is 0. This is seen using $E[Y] = f(x)$.

*Edit*

I am not that sure on how to prove 
$$E[(Y-f(x))(\hat{f}(x)-f(x))] = 0$$
If we assume independence between $\epsilon = Y - f(x)$ and $\hat{f}(x)-f(x)$, then the proof is trivial, as we can split the expected value in two products, the first of them being $0$. However, I am not so sure about the fact that we can assume this independence.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more on why the third term is 0? Why $E[Y]=f(x)$ leads the third term to be 0? How to calculate the third term?

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Since ϵ is the noise, I think the noise should be independent from the model or the data. So the independence you assumed should be valid.

Comment: Indeed, I think this should be it. Good work

Comment: The third term is zero because: 1. As someone pointed out, the noise is independent of the data.
2. The noise is assumed to be normally distributed with mean zero.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from some standard definitions really. There is a similar question on [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123320/mse-decomposition-to-variance-and-bias-squared) that has good answers. There are related questions there that might be worth looking through too, [like this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152882/question-about-bias-variance-tradeoff?rq=1).

---

The $\sigma^2_{e}$, which is basically the *noise* that comes with a **random variable**. Perhaps there isn't much of it, but we normally just write it at the end of such equations.

In the context of a real world machine learning problem, I also sometimes think of that term as accounting for information that I just do not have the possibility to explain, with the data that I have. So in that particular project, it is as good as irreducible error.